# Conditional formatting for each individual row

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formatting, conditional-statements

I am working with an excel sheet with numbers in several rows right below each other. I want to conditionally format each row, so that the all values of this row which are below the value in column A and above the value in column B of the same row are marked. E.g. in row 20, all values below the value of A20 are marked yellow and all values above B20 are marked red. In row 21, all values below A21 and B21...

I created a loop through the rows 20-22 for now, the range will vary in later applications. The loop now is always referring back to A20 and B20 instead of referring to values i would like to use for each row (e.g A21 and B21 for row 21). I tried to use Ai and Bi, but that did not work. This is where i would need the main help - which syntax can i use to refer to the cells i want instead of A20 and B20?

Additionally, is there a way to mark the conditionally formated cells with real colors? E.g conditionally yellow filled with yellow? At the moment I am selecting the conditionally formated cells by hand and add a fill.

Thank you for your help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 20 To 22

Rows(i).Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=$B$20"

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=$A$20"


Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: You can just format the entire range in one go, there is no need to loop. Just specify >=$B20 and <=$A20 as the values so that the column reference is absolute but the row reference is not.

Comment: Did you try formula based conditional formatting could achieve this?

Comment: Thank you so much, the specification of >=$B20 and <=$A20 was the charm!